# Are questions asking for how to treat pets with vet treatments, e.g. medicines, on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, questions, scope, asking-questions

This question [Amoxicillin dosage and length of treatment for cat?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/15017/amoxicillin-dosage-and-length-of-treatment-for-cat) bothers me somewhat. We have a pet owner asking how to dose antibiotics for their pets, without having a vet checking the pets.

> I run a small cat sanctuary and am currently between vets. I'm trying to learn to do some basic treating on my own. I know when a cat is sick enough to call a vet so please don't just tell me to go to a vet. That doesn't answer my question.

This comment does not make the question on topic for the site.

My understanding of this site is that we are not to advise on veterinarian treatment as such, but to support on issues surrounding vet treatment (plus other pet topics).

What's the consensus?

Answer (score 3):

The reality is that antibiotics can be purchased in the US at [farm supply stores relatively inexpensively](https://www.tractorsupply.com/tsc/product/combi-pen-48-100-ml-bimeda-antibacteria?cm_vc=-10005) no vet visit is required.

The US has fairly tight drug controls, in some other countries more drugs are available. Pets.se serves a global community. Any drug or medicine that is lawfully available to pet owners in any country should be in scope for questions.

Comment: I'm cool with that. Just need a firm idea of where we stand. Mind you a consensus of 1 does not a consensus make lol Hopefully some more people will vote or post on their thoughts.

Comment: Concur, I suggest you wait a few days before accepting an answer. Others may post answers that better define the group consensus.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with James that since antibiotics are available commonly, we shouldn't necessarily refuse to answer questions about them.

I also appreciate that the answers in the linked question addressed other issues (you can't really be sure it's a UTI with a free catch sample and test strips, and antibiotics are often given in cats when its NOT a UTI for no benefit). As long as we're able to produce high quality answers like this, I don't see an issue.